# Parsing a script in discord.py to display

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, discord.py, list-comprehension

```py
@bot.command()
    async def test(ctx):
        with open("C:\\bot\\cn.txt", 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                values = line.split("|")
                for value in values:
                dbdc = [dbdc for dbdc in values[2:3] if dbdc == 'DOOMBIRD DOOMCAVE' and list.count[0] < 6]
                print(dbdc[0])
```

Right now, it's displaying the users who don't exceed the value 6, so that works, but it's not filtering it out to match the text.

What I am trying to make it do, is read the txt file, match values**[3]** to the text, ie 'DOOMBIRD DOOMCAVE'. Then, I want it to check *[1]* to see if it shows up more than 6 times. Finally, once those conditions are met, I want it to print the results. Unfortunately, it pops up with Index out of range.
[error message][1]

text file:
Declaring ID|*Declaring Ruler*|Declaring Nation|**Declaring Alliance**|Declaring Alliance ID|Declaring Team|Receiving ID|Receiving Ruler|Receiving Nation|Receiving Alliance|Receiving Alliance ID|Receiving Team|Status|Money|Technology|Soldiers|Date|Reason|Aid ID|

````py
Ignoring exception in command test:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\bot\eraserhead.py", line 343, in test
    print(dbdc[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\justi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range```
````

Comment: Please do not post pictures within your question, copy and paste your errors.